# Wiring HTML and JavaScript and CSS in a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in the `Assets` folder there are two folders for `javascripts` and `stylesheets`.
So I added a `spike.js` and a CSS file of `spikecss.css` to those folders and wrote some Javascript and CSS code fin them.

Now I am in the index.html page and writing something like this?  Which doesn't work. How do I wire all these thing together to work?

This is a test app mostly for the javascript side of the deal so I really don't have models, controllers,views at this point. I am drawing D3 chart in the JavaScript file so I just want to show them when I hit the webpage

**Javascript file:**

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var chart = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "chart");

chart.selectAll(chart)
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d){return d*5 +"px";});
```

**Index.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Here we go</title>
</head>
<body>

javascript_include_tag :defaults, "spike"

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which index.html file?  The one in /public or /app/views/something/?  You can't use embedded ruby in the /public/index.html...  use <script> tags in the <head> section instead as you would for any static HTML page.

Comment: the one in public folder.

Comment: show your /assets/application.js, and /assets/application.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Based on Ryan's method used in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/408-ember-part-1?view=asciicast), you can have a dynamic `index.html.erb` page with just these 2 steps (the original, slightly more complex answer can be seen below):

First, set your routes.rb file to look like this:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'application#index'
end
```

Next, move your `/public/index.html` file to `/app/views/application/index.html.erb`.  Don't just copy it - *move* it.  This means you should not have an index.html file in your `/public` directory.

Congratulations, you now have a dynamic index page that can handle ERB markup.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The `/public/index.html` file is statically served, so you'll need to write it as if you weren't using Rails.  Add your css and javascript locations to the `<head>` section, using `<link>` and `<script>` respectively as you would for any vanilla HTML page.

If you prefer to do this the Rails way, you'll need at the very minimum:

- an entry in `routes.rb`
- a corresponding empty controller
- and an `index.html` file (or `index.html.erb`, `index.html.haml`, etc) at `/app/views/some_name/` where `some_name` is the same as your controller name (minus the word 'controller').

You can then add your custom file names to your `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` and `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` manifests to have them pulled into the page.

Alternatively, you can edit your `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` template manually using embedded ruby.  See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-javascript-files-with-the-javascript_include_tag) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-css-files-with-the-stylesheet_link_tag) for documentation for how to do this.

Oh, one other thing - the javascript you wrote will execute before the DOM has loaded as it stands right now.  To avoid this, you'll need to wrap it with something like:

```
$(function(){ /* your code here */ });
```